# UDP Port Forwarding

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, udp, wireguard

I got 2 servers Named A and B, both are in different data centers and just have internet access.
I need the incoming UDP connections to a particular port on server A to be forwarded to a specific port on server B.
ssh tunneling is just for TCP.
I could not get udp2raw working.
any idea?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p UDP -i eth0 -d 192.0.2.1 --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.0.2.2:8888
```

eventually add this if your FROWARD policy is not ACCEPTing all

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p UDP -d 192.0.2.1 --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I got confused a bit, Imagine I'm going to forward incoming UDP connections on port 10 in Host B with address B.B.B.B to UDP port 20 on host A with address A.A.A.A
Can you edit the command with these parameters? then I can replace parameters

Comment: Don't I need a process to listen the specific port on forwarding host?

Comment: your statement "forward incoming UDP connections on port 10 in Host B with address B.B.B.B to UDP port 20 on host A"
is the opposite of your original question: "incoming UDP connections to a particular port on server A to be forwarded to a specific port on server B"
that's not clear.
No, you don't need a listening process. iptables (linux kernel) intercept the packet before

Comment: I just replaced A with B, imagine the second statement, now how parameters should be replaced?